# Get the String Count in a String - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, birt

**How to find the String Count in a String in JavaScript?**

Ex:

```
https://localhost/public/10e900fe-0470-11eb-93c6-f377ab03a336//
```

Get the `//` occurrence count.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var string = "https://localhost/public/10e900fe-0470-11eb-93c6-f377ab03a336//";
console.log((string.match(/\/\//g) || []).length);
```

You can try below code:

```
var string = "https://localhost/public/10e900fe-0470-11eb-93c6-f377ab03a336//";
console.log((string.match(/\/\//g) || []).length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a="https://localhost/public/10e900fe-0470-11eb-93c6-f377ab03a336//"
var count= a.split("//").length-1;
console.log(count)
```

you can find the count by splitting it into an array and find the length of the array

```
var a="https://localhost/public/10e900fe-0470-11eb-93c6-f377ab03a336//"
var count= a.split("//").length-1; // its 2
```